# At ubuntu server boot cli, how can I check if internet is configured?

Tags: 14.04, boot, server, preseed

Basically I want to preseed ubuntu server set up but it keeps on saying file can't be loaded, so I was thinking maybe there is something wrong with my internet connection. But there is no ping or ifconfig at boot menu, so I don't know how to check that.

Comment: Press ctrl-alt-f2 (or f3, f4) to get to a TTY and use ifconfig.

Comment: Why in the boot menu? Reboot the machine and use the console as muru has proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try live booting?

Once at the cli, ping googles DNS server with

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -c 4
```

That proves you're reaching the outside world